# Update row being inserted

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table named Tickets. I want to auto generate a ramdom number for the serial_ticket field of the row being inserted. How can I do that? This is my body trigger code:

```
BEGIN 

    set new.Serial_Ticket := (SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * 99999) AS serial_ticket

    FROM tickets

    WHERE "serial_ticket" NOT IN (SELECT serial_ticket FROM tickets));

    END
```

I have no errors but its not working I just get "null" when I insert a new row. I'm Using phpmyadmin on Wampserver (localhost) and a C# app.

The goal is to request the server to place a new ticket on database and generate a ticket serial, then insert each item being sold on a different table named "item" but I need the ticket serial to be generated after for link these items with the ticket and avoid duplicates.

PD: Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

this doesn't look logical,  serial_ticket is not defined yet when you use it in the where condition.  According to the docs,

> It is not permissible to refer to a column alias in a WHERE clause,
>   because the column value might not yet be determined when
>   the WHERE clause is executed

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-alias.html

generate a unique prefix based on one of your unique fields, then attach a random number (with leading zeros) . you dont have to use a trigger and it will be much faster since you can do it while inserting the row.

Comment: Thanks that fixed my issue!

Comment: you are most welcome, but if it did fix your issue then shouldn't it be the correct answer!